# Where is "language" for Respondents in Surveymonkey API V3

Tags: multilingual, surveymonkey

When downloading an `XLS` file from a multilingual survey, `Column` I has the language.

I don't see that in the `API` data returned for Responses. It is there, once only, for the survey itself.

Where is it please for each respondent?

Also, at what point in the process is the language determined?
Thank you
Patrick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can currently be found under the 'metadata' field here: https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#surveys-id-responses-id-details

This is missing from the bulk responses endpoint (https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#surveys-id-responses-bulk), so we'll add it there shortly.

Comment: I see that now, the metadata field in bulk responses is {}. Are there any other differences between individual responses and bulk, in terms of extra data available?

Comment: Hello Adam that was a year and a half ago you were going to add it "shortly". When will that be done please?